# Can N, q be shared for multiple users when using SRP-6A

Tags: srp

Is it considered bad practice to use the same N and q parameters for all users in an SRP-6A based authentication system?

I know that q MUST be a Sophie Germain prime and N a safe prime, but can they be generated ahead of time and be somewhat fixed / hardcoded in the client and server? Or should I generate a fresh pair for each new user registration?

I imagine, it's better to have a different one for each account, but if it's not affecting the security of the system in any way...

Comment: what is `q`? the parameters are usually defined as `N` a safe prime and `g` its generator which you can create from OpenSSL with `openssl dhparam -text <bit-length>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pre-compute and hardcode `N` and `g` into your client and server. There's no harm in doing this. I do not believe that using per-user `N` will provide any additional security.

It is common practice to define SRP parameters for a particular application or (larger) protocol, see e.g. [RFC 5054](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054#appendix-A).